# fail2ban Jail starts but no connections are showed

Tags: ssh, fail2ban, jail

I installed fail2ban on my Ubuntu server.

It seems to starts fine:

```
cat fail2ban.log
2023-12-07 14:55:27,758 fail2ban.server         [803]: INFO    --------------------------------------------------
2023-12-07 14:55:27,758 fail2ban.server         [803]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.11.2
2023-12-07 14:55:27,759 fail2ban.observer       [803]: INFO    Observer start...
2023-12-07 14:55:27,767 fail2ban.database       [803]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2023-12-07 14:55:27,768 fail2ban.database       [803]: WARNING New database created. Version '4'
2023-12-07 14:55:27,769 fail2ban.jail           [803]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd'
2023-12-07 14:55:27,778 fail2ban.jail           [803]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' uses pyinotify {}
2023-12-07 14:55:27,779 fail2ban.jail           [803]: INFO    Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2023-12-07 14:55:27,780 fail2ban.filter         [803]: INFO      maxLines: 1
2023-12-07 14:55:27,790 fail2ban.filter         [803]: INFO      maxRetry: 5
2023-12-07 14:55:27,790 fail2ban.filter         [803]: INFO      findtime: 600
2023-12-07 14:55:27,790 fail2ban.actions        [803]: INFO      banTime: 600
2023-12-07 14:55:27,790 fail2ban.filter         [803]: INFO      encoding: UTF-8
2023-12-07 14:55:27,790 fail2ban.filter         [803]: INFO    Added logfile: '/var/log/auth.log' (pos = 0, hash = dbc10cda87971348abf435b463c625fcaf25d6de)

2023-12-07 16:32:52,352 fail2ban.jail           [3466]: INFO    Creating new jail 'sshd'
2023-12-07 16:32:52,354 fail2ban.jail           [3466]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' uses poller {}
2023-12-07 16:32:52,354 fail2ban.jail           [3466]: INFO    Initiated 'polling' backend
2023-12-07 16:32:52,354 fail2ban.filter         [3466]: INFO      maxLines: 1
2023-12-07 16:32:52,361 fail2ban.filter         [3466]: INFO      maxRetry: 3
2023-12-07 16:32:52,361 fail2ban.filter         [3466]: INFO      findtime: 900
2023-12-07 16:32:52,361 fail2ban.actions        [3466]: INFO      banTime: 900
2023-12-07 16:32:52,361 fail2ban.filter         [3466]: INFO      encoding: UTF-8
2023-12-07 16:32:52,361 fail2ban.filter         [3466]: INFO    Added logfile: '/var/log/auth.log' (pos = 106290, hash = dbc10cda87971348abf435b463c625fcaf25d6de)
2023-12-07 16:32:52,362 fail2ban.jail           [3466]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started
```

When I look for its status it also seems ok:

```
sudo fail2ban-client status
Status
|- Number of jail:  1
`- Jail list:   sshd
```

I added some lines in the log /var/log/fail2ban.log:

```
[sshd]

# To use more aggressive sshd modes set filter parameter "mode" in jail.local:
# normal (default), ddos, extra or aggressive (combines all).
# See "tests/files/logs/sshd" or "filter.d/sshd.conf" for usage example and details.
#mode   = normal
enabled = true
port    = ssh
backend = polling
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
bantime = 900
banaction = iptables-allports
findtime = 900
maxretry = 3
```

When I do `cat fail2ban.log` no connections are showed after `2023-12-07 16:32:52,362 fail2ban.jail           [3466]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' started`.
I'm doing ssh connections to the server through my MacBook and they appear at `/var/log/auth.log`, however nothing appears at `fail2ban.log`.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? It could be that journalctl logging is being used, then you need to change the backend configuration of fail2ban to systemd. Do you get any output when you do `journalctl -u ssh`, this is to check if you have journal logs for ssh. newer distributions moved to journalctl logging. T

Answer (score 0):

Try to Set your backend to auto or systemd and then reload fail2ban.

I would recommend this config for your jails

```
[ssh]
enabled = true
port = ssh
filter = ssh
backend = systemd
maxretry = 3
bantime = 600


# Block DDOS on ssh
[ssh-ddos]
enabled = true
port = ssh,sftp
filter = sshd-ddos
backend = systemd
maxretry = 2
bantime = 600
```

And to see the banned ips you need to check the jail itself `fail2ban-client status ssh` (when you implement my config), your config `fail2ban-client status sshd` (but on debian based distributions sshd is the ssh service, it's just ssh)